# Restrict Google Maps V3 Direction Services to stay in Country

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a google map that plots Electric Vehicle (EV) charging station across Canada, and only in Canada. The point of the map is for users to plot their route within Canada and see what EV stations are available along the way. However when searching for Vancouver -> Toronto, the route goes through the United States. How can I ensure the route stays within Canada?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using waypoints.

Comment: This feature was requested some months ago, perhaps you should give it a star to show your interest in this feature: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3890

Comment: You could also parse the directions returned by the Direction Service as this guy did: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/kvNk7bt14aY/vvIJheNzckkJ

Answer (score 0):

In any kind of geocoding situation if you have a preferred route, known location, etc, it is generally going to be a better idea to store that preferred data in some way. Then, whenever a query is made for a particular route, location, etc, you use that data rather than a geocoding service.

This often speeds things up, offers you greater control and protects you from a route or location changing without your knowing it. Geocoding is not a fixed or exact science, if you are querying a remote service there is no guarantee that the input that works today will work tomorrow.

So, if you have routes that deviate from *what you know to be correct* - fix them and store them. When a query is made for that route, rather than geocoding for directions simply return the route.

It should be easy to get some kind of traffic data for the main routes in Canada.
Along with location data of EV stations you could pre-compute, devise, optimise the most popular routes before any user geocoding query is even made.